# java web services from .net client

Tags: java, asp.net, .net, web-services, jakarta-ee

I am trying to make a .net client for a java web service made using JAX-WS 2.0 . Actually the web service maintains session of the client. Well i did create a client from java and it worked. But i am having problem in consuming the web service from .net client. According to the specification of that web service i have to set the SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY of the BindingProvider true to indicate whether or not the client wants to participate in session with service endpoint. It is done in java client in following way:

```
Hello proxy = new HelloService().getHelloPort();
((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext()
    .put(BindingProvider.SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY,true);
```

I dont know how to do such from .net.

Comment: Possibly answered here - http://www.java.net/node/681084 - ?

Comment: Thank You Jon for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

In older versions, there was a *CookieContainer* but you can use this

```cs
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding {AllowCookies = true};
using (var svc = new ServiceReference1.MyWSClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8080/myApp/myWS")));
```